# Problema al tratar de validar si un usuario ya existe

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estoy realizando unas validaciones en el Registro de una página que estoy haciendo con `MVC`, entonces quiero validar que el nombre del usuario no exista en mi base de datos, si este nombre existe debería salir un aviso apenas la persona escriba el nombre en el input sin necesidad de mandar todo el formulario para dar el error, estoy utilizando `Ajax` y `jQuery` para validar esto, pero no me funciona.

Me arroja el siguiente **warning** por la consola del navegador:

> **Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable**

Aquí dejo una captura de todo lo que sale en la consola: 
[image: Warning Consola]

El código que estoy haciendo es el siguiente:

```
    $("#usuarioRegistro").change(function(){
        var usuario = $("#usuarioRegistro").val(); 
        var datos = new FormData();
        datos.append("validarUsuario", usuario);

        $.ajax({
            url:"views/modules/ajax.php",
            method:"POST",
            data: datos,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(respuesta){
                console.log("Respuesta de PHP: "+respuesta);
                if(respuesta == 0){
                  $("label[for='usuarioRegistro'] span").html('<p>Este Usuario ya Existe</p>');      
                }else{
                    $("label[for='usuarioRegistro'] span").html("");
                }
            }
        });

    });
```

Módulo ajax.php:

```php
    <?php
      require_once "../../controllers/controller.php";
      require_once "../../models/crud.php";

      class Ajax{

        public $validarUsuario;
        public function validarUsuarioAjax(){
            $datos = $this->validarUsuario;
            $respuesta = MvcController::validarUsuarioController($datos);
            echo $respuesta;
        }
     }
     $aux = new Ajax();
     $aux->validarUsuario = $_POST["validarUsuario"];
     $aux->validarUsuarioAjax();
    ?>
```

Controlador:

```php
    //Validar Usuario Existente
    //------------------------------------
    public static function validarUsuarioController($validarUsuario){
        $datosController = $validarUsuario;
        $respuesta = Datos::validarUsuarioModel($datosController, "usuarios");

        if(count($respuesta["usuario"]) > 0){
            echo 0;
        }else{
            echo 1;
        }
    }
```

Modelo:

```
  public static function validarUsuarioModel($datosModel, $tabla){
        $stmt= Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT usuario FROM $tabla WHERE usuario=:usuario");
        $stmt->bindParam(":usuario", $datosModel, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetch(); 
        $stmt->close();

    }

}
```

Cabe destacar que `$respuesta["usuario"]` contiene caracteres que provienen del `fetch()` del modelo, que devuelve un array entonces no entiendo por qué me da un **warning** con la función `count()` de `php`, si alguien sabe que tengo malo me sería de mucha ayuda! gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema esta en que `Datos::validarUsuarioModel` regresa un valor que no se le puede aplicar el count ya que posiblemente es un valor numérico,cadena o un bolean, intenta cambiado tu `if`, puede ser también que te este regresando un valor `null`

Ejemplo:

```
if(isset($respuesta["usuario"])&&$respuesta["usuario"]){
   echo 0;
}else{
   echo 1;
}
```

Comment: Lo que me genera duda es que me estoy guiando de un curso y con count si funciona en el video, pero a mi no y es lo que no entiendo, pero usando isset si me funciona gracias

Comment: Tal vez el curso que estas siguiendo esté usando una versión de PHP anterior a la que estás usando en tu máquina.